# Create subdomains in cpanel by using php

Tags: php, subdomain

What I want is to create subdomains in cpanel using the API in php. Just like steve.hubflx.com, jeff.hubflx.com or mike.hubflx.com. I have been searching since three days but haven't found anything useful or maybe I don't understand the answers that I got. Can someone give me a working example with a little bit of explanation so that I can create sub domains dynamically. Or if any one has this working then can you please send me the code.

I have also tried the code I found on this site
http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/cpanel-subdomains-creator.php.. but could not make it out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php/blob/master/xmlapi.php (xmlapi_query function in particular)?

Comment: Yes i tried that.. But when i run the page i dont see any errors or any echos or any thing on the page. When i see the sub domains in my cpanel it is not created.. @ Daniel Bang